# Gerar relatório somente com dados passados via parâmetro IReports

Tags: java, relatório, ireport, jasper

Normalmente geramos relatório pelo IReports baseado em consulta ao banco de dados, só que agora me deparo a com seguinte questão, vou montar um relatório baseado nos dados mostrados no visual do cliente, no caso é redundante buscar a informação novamente no banco.

Fiz um teste simples passando 1 informação via parâmetro e tentando gerar um view.

Mas não gerou nenhuma página, acredito que seja algo simples porém não estou conseguindo gerar esta saída.

No relatório só tenho um parâmetro criado e adicionado no campo detalhe no mesmo.

E assim que faço a chamada dele.

```
 public void ImpressaoRelatorio() {

    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("RelatorioParametro.jasper");

    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    parametros.put("descProduto", "Produto Teste");


    try {

        ReportUtils.openReport("Relatorio Produto teste", inputStream, parametros,
                ConnectionFactory.getAgilConnection());

    } catch (SQLException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JRException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Porém ao executar ele retorna em branco.

Comment: Você está passando pelo menos um elemento na collection do seu datasource? Algo como: JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(colecaoComUmaInstancia); ... JasperPrint prt = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + caminhoRelatorio), parametros, ds);

Answer (score 0):

No ireport, Você pode adicionar parâmetro via código ou via aplicação:
Segue um exemplo via código

```
<parameter name="cdmov" class="java.lang.Object" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Long(12883)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
         P.NOME
          FROM
      PESSOA P
  WHERE
   AND  M.CD_PESSOA = $P{cdmov}]]>
    </queryString>
```

Ai pelo java você chama o código

```
HashMap valores = new HashMap();
valores.put("cdmov",cdmov);
```

Comment: Mas no caso não quero fazer um consulta via banco de dados.

Comment: então você chama só o parametro

Comment: Vou exemplificar na questão.